# problem with friday night funkin compilation

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib

I am trying to use the compiled page of git hub but after installing and doing everything it asks for, when using the command `lime test windows`  I get the following error.

```
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/polymod/git/polymod/format/XMLMerge.hx:189: characters 10-23 : Warning : This typedef is deprecated in favor of haxe.xml.Access
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/polymod/git/polymod/format/XMLMerge.hx:189: characters 30-43 : Warning : This typedef is deprecated in favor of haxe.xml.Access
```

If you could help me with this problem that I have, you would help me since I want to be able to create my own mod and enter the world of programming starting with this.

Comment: Those are not errors, merely warnings that can safely be igored. If compilation doesn't work, that's not what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Those **aren't** errors, they are **warnings** you are free to ignore them, if something doesn't work, that isn't the issue.